# RestTemplate POST request RequestParams and RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I have a server and a client. I am using Spring to map http requests on the server and RestTemplate to make requests to the server.

Server code looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping (value="/someEndPoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String configureSettings(
@RequestParam(required=false) Integer param1,
@RequestParam(required=false) Long param2,
@RequestBody String body)
{

if(param1 != null)
// do something

if(body not empty or null)
//do something

}
```

Client side:

```
String postUrl = "http://myhost:8080/someEndPoint?param1=val1"
restTemplate.postForLocation(postUrl, null);
```

This works in that the correct action is triggered on the server side from param1
however, the body of the request also contains:
param1=val1
The request body when it is set it will json so all I want is to be able to set other parameters without setting the body.
I know I am using the restTemplate incorrectly so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing an `HTTP POST`, but you are not providing an object to put `POST`ed.  Spring's `RestTemplate` is trying to figure out what you want to `POST`, so it looks and sees that the query string of the url has something, so it tries to use that.

Do not add a query string to a `POST`, just provide the object that you want to `POST`.

```
String postUrl = "http://myhost:8080/someEndPoint"
restTemplate.postForLocation(postUrl, new ParamModel("val1"));
```

The book [`Spring in Action (3rd edition)`](http://www.manning.com/walls4/) covers `RestTemplate` (and REST in general) pretty well.  I would recommend taking a look at it.